# How to flag a user who posts a duplicate answer

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers

This answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/29911145/3576412 is same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/29766446/3576412, what is appropriate flag for such answer ?

Comment: Flag for moderator attention, including a link to the answer it duplicates and a comment along the lines of *"blatant copy of part of an existing answer"*

Comment: Read this [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered)

Comment: i think this user is doing same for many answers, just checked on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php/29911602#29911602 that asnwer is same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/4526834/3576412

Comment: It also seems like someone is upvoting each answer. Could be sockpuppeting. But, benefit of the doubt... it could be that he's **only** guilty of plagiarism. ;)

Comment: Hah. He's also plagiarised w3schools for his [edit on the php wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3607050/revisions).

Comment: yeah seems like plagiarism, who else can use a line as ` PHP is a widely-used, free, and efficient alternative to competitors such as Microsoft's ASP.` :)

Comment: @Abhishek That's exactly what made me suspicious. Noone likes PHP that much.

Comment: I wonder, does plagiarism count as "inappropriate" from the flag menu?

Comment: @TravisJ, No, mods need to know what it is plagiarisied from, so you need to use a custom flag to tell them. Mods appreciate every bit of detail and information you give.

Comment: [They plagiarize blog posts too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29600714/464709). I left a flag.

Comment: @J.Steen - yeah, I saw the reputation pattern too; it appears in little 2- and 3-burst votes, but I've flagged them as possible undetected serial upvotes and/or sock puppets... considering the plagiarizing of answers *and* blog posts, I wouldn't be the least bit surprised at this point of there were more shenanigans.

Comment: They also apparently copied-and-pasted some text from W3Schools into the [php] tag:  http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7859300.  I'm going to just pretend they felt some compelling and justified reason to plagiarize W3Schools and edit the PHP tag, and that they weren't just [badge hunting](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3526079/suresh-ratten?tab=activity&sort=badges).

Comment: It also seems he had serial up-votes reversed [( 60 rep )](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3526079/suresh-ratten?tab=reputation) on April 25th, That almost confirms the use of sock-puppets.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could raise a **flag** as "**`in need of moderator intervention`**". And explain in details why you think the answer is some some form of plagiarism.

The flag clearly mentions to *Be specific and detailed*.

[image]

For short and precise answers, it is easy to make out if it is a blatant copy paste of other posted answer. However, it might need some effort for lengthy answers to understand the plagiarism. But, as others have said, moderators would definitely appreciate the detailed explanation.

Mostly, the participants also play an important role to identify such plagiarism. You would see the downvotes, and when the downvotes go beyond 3, the answer is grayed out.

Just another observation, in the links pointed out by you, the user seems to be keen to earn the bounty with his plagiarism. However, he failed to fool the community!