# Declined flag on duplicate answer

Tags: support, declined-flags, duplicate-answers

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55385703/9609843) is surely a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38953970/9609843) but my flag "in need of moderator intervention" ([this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291680/9609843) recommends to use this flag in such cases) with text "Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/38953970/9609843" (original formatting) was declined with "Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see What is Flagging?". So, did I really need to choose another flag?

Comment: did you say it was a duplicate? or did you say it was plagiarism. Also, how is that post plagiarism and not the accepted one?

Comment: Yes, I said "Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/38953970/9609843", I have already stated this in the question body.

Comment: Yeah, so, you weren't clear. Duplicate answers aren't a problem, it's plagiarism that's a problem. but i'm not entirely sure that this particular case could even be considered plagiarism.

Comment: @KevinB: It's at least a bit problematic when there is already an answer with the same code which is two years older.

Answer (score -8):

The answer isn't duplicated because one answer reads (quite concisely):

> Add the extension to `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( quickbed_logo.png )` because Rails cannot guess it.

versus

> `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( quickbed_logo.png )`

A reviewer in a hurry who would see those two answers side-by-side would be willing to give the benefit of the doubt to someone because, who knows - after two or so years, the answer may still be the same - but would likely favor the one with the more detailed explanation as opposed to the one without it.

It isn't the same case that the actual explanation was lifted with variables or expressions changed.  It's just the case that someone thought to repost the same solution.  Admittedly that's not helpful, and while it isn't exactly plagiarism, it's not a good answer, either.  We have **other** ways to deal with poor answers.

I think the answer should simply be downvoted and/or removed by the community, and we can definitely handle *that* much.

Comment: Wait...what's the difference between these two answers again? Why should we save the one that does nothing more than recapitulate the code posted several years earlier, absent an explanation?

Comment: Did I say ***save*** it @CodyGray?  Pretty sure that I said it should be downvoted/deleted.  We don't flag crap answers, we downvote them.

Comment: Oh. Well, if you think it should be deleted, then why not flag it? That's what flags are for, after all: "this answer needs to be deleted". Downvotes are for *incorrect* answers, because moderators don't judge technical correctness. This was a pretty objective case of a late, useless regurgitation.

Comment: @CodyGray:  I see your point - we don't want people who can't downvote or delete questions like this to spin up a new Meta question with every occurrence of this incident.  However, absent context the flag to initiate this request was still declined - likely because the moderator handling it thought at a glance that it was a dupe closure request instead of a duplicate answer.  I still see no harm in downvoting it *anyway* and casting a delete vote *anyway* if the person seeing this is eligible to.

Comment: No, of course there's nothing wrong with taking post hoc action. If you still think the post should be deleted, then you should vote to delete. Personally, I would delete it instantly, if it weren't for trying to have a discussion about it on Meta. But that isn't the question here. The question is, why was the flag declined? Yes, I suspect you're probably right about it being misinterpreted as pointing out a duplicate question. But putting that misinterpretation aside (which could have been easily corrected by writing a clearer flag message), I think answers like this should be deleted by mods